# Como pegar o primeiro elemento diferente de zero?

Tags: r

estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma matriz e quero percorrê-la e pegar a primeira linha que tenha todos os elementos diferentes de zero. Por exemplo:

```
a = matrix(c(rep(0,4), 1:16), ncol = 4, byrow = T)
b = matrix(c(1:4, rep(0,4), 5:16), ncol = 4, byrow = T)
d = matrix(c(1:8,rep(0,4) , 9:16), ncol = 4, byrow = T)
```

A resposta de "a" seria a linha 2, a resposta de "b" seria a linha 1 e a resposta de "d" seria linha 1.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente a seguinte função:

```
primeira_linha_nao_nula <- function(m){
  vetor <- apply(m, 1, function(x) return(all(x != 0)))
  indice <- NULL
  if(max(vetor) == 1){
    indice <- order(vetor, decreasing = T)[1]  
  }
  return(m[indice,])
}
```

A primeira linha percorre a matriz e cria um vetor, chamado `vetor`, que é `TRUE` quando a linha possui todos elementos diferentes de zero.
Em seguida ela verifica se existe pelo menos um `TRUE` nesse vetor, para depois retornar o menor índice que é `TRUE`.

```
> primeira_linha_nao_nula(a)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> primeira_linha_nao_nula(b)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> primeira_linha_nao_nula(d)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Daniel, me expressei errado, quero que retorne os elementos da matriz, ou seja, todos os elementos da linha 2, 1 e 1.

Comment: Vou editar, mas é apenas uma linha a mais!